# how to format the JSON for boto aws sdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cloudformation

I m using boto and cloudformation to orchestrate few resource

For creating templates for cloud formation. I m reading a json-file from my local disk and creating json-string to pass as a parameter for `template_body`

```
try:
  fileObj = open(filename,'r')
  json_data = json.loads(fileObj.read())
  return json_data
except IOError as e:
  print e
  exit()
```

And my cloud formation connection string and stack creation goes like this

```
 cfnConnectObj = cfn.connection.CloudFormationConnection(aws_access_key_id=aKey, aws_secret_access_key=sKey, is_secure=True,debug=2,path='/',validate_certs=True,region=region[3]) #created connection object for cloudformation service

stackID = cfnConnectObj.create_stack('demodrupal',template_body=templateJson, template_url=None,parameters=[],notification_arns=[],disable_rollback=False,timeout_in_minutes=None,capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM'],tags=None)
```

I m getting Boto Error `[ERROR]:{"Error":{"Code":"ValidationError","Message":"Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 1, column 3)","Type":"Sender"}`

Why is this error ?
I have used `json.loads` but still it shows Json not well formed. Is there anything i m missing ?

Please en-light me

**I m new to python and boto

Comment: `with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj: return json.load(file_obj)` is enough, no need to try-except there, and `json.load()` reads directly from a file object for you.

Comment: You need to **encode** to JSON, `templateJson` is probably a Python object, not JSON itself. Better still, do not decode from JSON at all, just send JSON directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but when i read a file through `open()` it becomes file object so i should convert it to JSON rite ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! man it worked fine i tot we need to convert fileobj to json or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json.loads takes json and converts it into a python object.  If you have a JSON file already you can just pass that file directly to the service.  Alternately you can load the JSON into python make any adjustments in python and then use json.dumps to get your well formed JSON.